# How can i create cascading dropdown Lists in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column, cascading

I have created a list on my SharePoint page with multiple dropdown menus when a new list is created. However, I was wondering that when an option is selected in the first drop down menu, if there was a way so that in the second drop down menu only certain options can be selected.

Currently my first dropdown menu is title projects and has all the main projects listed to choose (like 4 or 5 options). The second is for sub project. What I want to be able to do so say option 1 is chosen in the first drop down, only the certain sub projects that are related to option 1 in the first drop down appear in the second dropdown.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is actually called a 'Cascading drop down'. Are the SharePoint drop down fields that you are referring to actually Lookup fields looking into different lists? If yes, you can use SPServices and follow this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using). You will be able to filter the possible selection of a second lookup on the selected value of a first lookup field, as long as there is a relationship between the items of the 2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jurgen says you need create **Cascading dropdown** you will find below an easy tutorial follow it : [Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/)

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried that but what I am finding difficulty doing is that I have multiple sub platforms that fall under one major platform. so when I create the drop down I have the same top platform appear numerous times depending on how many sub-platforms lie under that main one. Is there a simple way that when I select Project "Global", the 5 platforms under that just appear?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers appear to target classic SharePoint, where scripts can more easily be added to pages.  In SharePoint Online, it's not quite as simple and would necessitate SPFx.

[This post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps) provides a means for doing the same in SPO using a custom Power App form.